# Can I use SQFP package instead LQFP for PCB design in Proteus 8?

Tags: pcb-design

I have to design sound card with CM108AH and its package is LQFP with 48 pins.
I use Proteus 8 for designing but there is no LQFP package for PCB.
Can I use SQFP 48 pins instead ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only substitute the footprint if it matches the footprint specifications for the part that you are using. It is up to you to look in the data sheet or other supplementary information provided by the manufacturer to find the suggested footprint specifications.

If they do not match then you use the footprint design facilities of your CAD package to create a suitable new footprint. Any CAD package worth it's salt has this capability. If yours does not then find one that does.